# How should I do a for loop for an entire column with an if clause inside (errors in brackets too, dont know why)

Tags: r, loops

In the dataset "portugal_2016", I have a column with football results "H", "A", "D" and I want to save in 2 new columns "home_points" and "visitor_points":

```
 for(i in 1:length(portugal_2016$X)) {
  if(portugal_2016$result == "H") {
    portugal_2016$home_points[i] <- 3
    portugal_2016$visitor_points[i] <- 0
    } else if (portugal_2016$result == "A") {
    portugal_2016$home_points[i] <- 0
    portugal_2016$visitor_points[i] <- 3
    } else (portugal_2016$result == "D") {
    portugal_2016$home_points[i] <- 1
    portugal_2016$visitor_points[i] <- 1
  }
}
```

Im experiencing errors in all brackets (dont know why) and not getting the result that I want.

```
    Error: unexpected '{' in:
"    portugal_2016$visitor_points[i] <- 3
    } else (portugal_2016$result == "D") {"
>     portugal_2016$home_points[i] <- 1
>     portugal_2016$visitor_points[i] <- 1
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could add some data to play with and also the actual error you are getting, as "errors in all brackets" is very general. Said so, I would try to replace `==` with `<-` as you are assigning a new value to the element. I would also tr to add `portugal_2016$home_points <- NULL` and `portugal_2016$visitor_points <- NULL` before the loop. Sometimes R complains as the column does not exists (the error message here helps). Finally, you don't need the `i++`, as you are already iterating from `1:lenght(portugal_2016$X)` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code

```
for(i in 1:length(portugal_2016$X)) {
  if(portugal_2016$result[i] == "H") {
    portugal_2016$home_points[i] <- 3
    portugal_2016$visitor_points[i] <- 0
  } 
  if (portugal_2016$result[i] == "A") {
    portugal_2016$home_points[i] <- 0
    portugal_2016$visitor_points[i] <- 3
  } 
  if (portugal_2016$result[i] == "D") {
    portugal_2016$home_points[i] <- 1
    portugal_2016$visitor_points[i] <- 1
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not working but thats because i was not fully clear (sorry I am new to this). The "X" is just a reference for the games(to loop until the season is finished), the "result" column is where I have the characters "A", "H", "D" so I think this is not entirely correct
 result <- portugal_2016$X[i]

Comment: @JoãoMachado see my updated code and try if it works

Comment: Nothing happened but atleast its running without the bracket errors. Do you know why I had that error before? And there is no need to increment i variable?

Comment: @what do you mean by "_Nothing happended_"? I have no idea what problem you encounter if you do not paste you errors in the post

Comment: I mean that the code run without erros but did not add any values to the columns in question

Comment: @JoãoMachado I just noticed that you used `==` to assign value to points. Then you can try my edited code again

Comment: @JoãoMachado You should use `<-` or `=` instead of `==` for assigning value to variable

Comment: Your code worked! thank you. Do you mind to take a look at my edited question and tell me why I have that error?

Comment: @JoãoMachado you used `else (portugal_2016$result == "D") {...`, while `else` should be followed by expression without any condition, so should be `else {...`